# How do I correctly start download from recycler view row?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, download, android-download-manager

Recycler view rows contain download buttons then when the user presses it download manager gets called to download the file and get the URI. This works but how do I handle when the user presses back or press home button? And how should I show the progress of a file that's still being downloaded when the user returns to the activity (typically after minimizing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start intent service when download a file and show status bar notification during download process. This will save download process.

Another way is to cancel download process when you leave that screen it's downloading. In that case you should stop downloading in Activity::onStop method

Comment: How should I show the progress indicator inside recycler view in the case when file is still downloading and the user left the activity and came back?

Comment: you should save downloading status somewhere in memory or permanent in storage and and repopulate recyclerview adapter with items which contains download status for each of them

Comment: If I set a flag (showProgress) on row item model then register/unregister a local broadcast receiver in bindViewHolder based on that would that good?

Comment: I think it'll cause a memory leak as the receiver will the initialized for each type of view holder and stays there even if it's not needed